# How to increase IsolatedStorage size?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I tried to increased IsoLatedStorage size with following code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   if (iso.FileExists(fileName))
     iso.DeleteFile(fileName);

   iso.IncreaseQuotaTo(iso.Quota + memoryStream.Length);
   //.....
}
```

but I can't, I checked iso.Quota befroe and after IncreaseQuotaTo call, it is not changed. Looks like code   iso.IncreaseQuotaTo(iso.Quota + memoryStream.Length); not working. Then I got error: There is not enough space to performer the operation. when I try to write memoryStream to IsolatedStream.

Not sure why. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is your problem, maybe the increase is not happening, because if you want to increase the isolated storage quota you must ask the user (with a messagebox or something like that), otherwise I don't think its going to work